Endomorphisms of torsion points of Drinfeld modules
A Drinfeld module is defined to be an $\mathbb F_q$-algebra morphism $\phi: \mathbb F_q[T] \rightarrow K\{\tau\}$, where $K=\mathbb F_{q^m}$ is a finite field and $K\{\tau\}$ is defined as the ring of non-commutative polynomials satisfying
$\tau \alpha=\alpha^q\tau$.
Let $g\in \mathbb F_q[T]$ and let us consider the $g$-torsion points of $\phi$, i.e. $\phi[g]=\ker(\phi(g))\subseteq \overline{\mathbb{F}}_q$. Suppose that $\phi[g]\subseteq K$. What are the elements of $K\{\tau\}$ that are endomorphisms for $\phi[g]$? Clearly, we have that $\phi(\mathbb F_q[T])$, and more in general $End(\phi)$ are endomorphisms for $\phi[g]$, but is there any other, which for example depends on $g$? What is the correct part of the theory to look at for this kind of question?
